# Approximation for square root of a quadratic

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am looking for a way to solve the following analytically:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t \sqrt{a(t) \, x^2+b(t) \, x+c(t)}\,\,dx = 0
$$
basically, the first step I want is an analytical integration of the square root containing my second order polynomial. I was thinking this couls be approximated with some sort of power series, I do need decent accuracy however at high x values. Then I take the derivative with respect to the upper limit, and find where it is 0 to find the minimum point of the integral. In other words I am attempting to find:

$$
\min{\left[\int_0^t \sqrt{a \, x^2+b \, x+c}\,\,dx\right]}
$$
Where my variable is $t$, and $a, b,c$ are functions of t.

Edit, my issue is is that $a, b, c$ are functions of t, I have updated that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Answer (score 2):

We have $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t \sqrt{a \, x^2+b \, x+c}\,\,dx 
= \sqrt{a \, t^2+b \, t+c} = 0
$$
So$$t=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$